# How to pass trustStore property in gradle build script

Tags: java, ssl, gradle, pkix

I am trying to generate classes for a SOAP webservice through a gradle script. I am using a plugin `gradle-jaxws-plugin` which is available in maven central.

My script looks like below:

```
buildscript {   
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "eu.schnuckelig.gradle:gradle-jaxws-plugin:1.0.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'jaxws'

jaxws {
    System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all') 
    packageName = 'com.myservice'
    wsdlURL = 'https://example.org/services/users.svc?wsdl'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

If I use this script as it is, I get following error

```
[ant:wsimport] [ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

One way of resolving this error, I tried is `gradle build -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`. This worked. But I want to pass these jvm properties in build script.

I tried `systemProperty.set()`, but it didn't work. I am trying with `gradle.properties`, but that doesn't work either. Is there a clean way to pass these properties? Also I am wondering how I will handle this in production when I will have an automated build.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Typically, since such data are sensitive they should be passed via command line or - if you have an automated build in production - should be configured in system via e.g. environment variables (this is how it's handled most often).

You can configure system properties via `gradle.properties` but they [should be prepend](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) with `systemProp` prefix, so:

**gradle.properties**:

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Also the following piece of code put in `build.gradle` just under `apply` section should work as well:
**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {   
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "eu.schnuckelig.gradle:gradle-jaxws-plugin:1.0.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'jaxws'

System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStore', 'cacerts')
System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword', 'changeit')
```

Comment: build.gradle option you mentioned, I have tried that before, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This response helped me after spending 3-4 days on a issue in gradle. Thanks a lot @Opal

Comment: Thank you Opal! This solved my problem in using the "maven-publish" plugin in publishing to a nexus repository using https.  I tried both approaches, and both work as advertised.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
configurations {
    jaxws
}

dependencies {
    jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
}

task wsimport {
    ext.destDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/generated")
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType', 'pkcs12')
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.keyStore', 'client.pfx')
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword', 'xxxxxxxxx')
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.keyPassword', 'xxxxxxxxx')
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStore', 'truststore.jks')
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword', 'xxxxxxxx')
    System.setProperty('sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation','true')
    doLast {
        ant {
            sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
            destDir.mkdirs()
            taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                    classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                    classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath
            )
            wsimport(keep: true,
                    destdir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                    sourcedestdir: destDir,
                    extension: "true",
                    verbose: "false",
                    quiet: "false",
                    package: "com.example.client.api",
                    xnocompile: "true",
                    wsdl: 'https://test.com/test.asmx?wsdl') {
                xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn wsimport
    source wsimport.destDir
}
```