# Intellij IDEA Certificate Error On Gradle Build

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'am using intellij IDEA 2021.3 version.
I'am having "PKIX PATH Building" issue during gradle build. I have imported required certificates to project's jdk, also to JAVA_HOME's jdk , and also Intellij ( via File-> Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates ). According to [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html) there has to be JVM Options in the gradle settings but I could not find it.
[image]

Comment: You have installed a JDK?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have also defined system environment of JAVA_HOME.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66237630/2000323 about how to configure the JDK that is used by Gradle for the untrusted certificate.