# Graddle wrapper command gives 'Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath''

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka

**I tried many of similar solutions - had no luck.**

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, following [this](https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/transform-a-stream-of-events/kstreams.html#configure-the-project) Confluent tutorial I've managed to get everything running several times without any problems but now when I run `gradle wrapper` I get:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'pmuStream01'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.3.
> > Required by:
> > project : > com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.1.0
> > > Could not resolve org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.3.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.13.3/log4j-core-2.13.3.pom'.
> > > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE,
> > class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > > Could not resolve org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.3.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.13.3/log4j-core-2.13.3.pom'.
> > > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE,
> > class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

I can easily wget all `pom` files in questions. DNS, ping, network - all works as usual ok.
I've updated java 8, gradle and system to latest. Rebooted system. I don't have any other java versions. Removed .gradle folder each time - nothing helped.

It seems silly that I should do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43486698/2119941) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed and purged Java, Gradle and Maven with all configurations and dependencies.

After that I've installed them again and now build went ok.