# Gradle build fails java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation on raspberry running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle

I am trying to build an empty gradle application with the following build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20220924'
    implementation group: 'uk.co.caprica', name: 'vlcj', version: '4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I try to build I get the following error:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.json:json:20220924.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.json:json:20220924.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/json/json/20220924/json-20220924.pom'.
            > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
   > Could not resolve uk.co.caprica:vlcj:4.8.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve uk.co.caprica:vlcj:4.8.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/4.8.1/vlcj-4.8.1.pom'.
            > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

What I tried so far with no success:

- add maven certificate to jvm cacerts

What I am using

- gradle 7.4
- jdk and jre 11
- ubuntu 20.04 (raspberry aarch64)

The maven repo exists and I am a bit hopeless what should I do. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance if you can help!

UPDATE:
As [@dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) recommended, I ran the build with stacktrace and got the following error:

```
java.security.KeyManagementException: problem accessing trust store
```

Tried to reinstall java but the same problem exist.

Comment: As it told you, use `--stacktrace` to get the stacktrace, and look especially at the 'caused by' block(s). The most common cause I have seen for this is that you have sysprops `javax.net.ssl.keyStore*` set wrong. Note it isn't caused (or solved) by the repo(s) you are connecting to; this is a problem purely within your JVM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same problem as me just set the variable for

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
```

to where your cacerts are located.
For me it was: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/lib/security/cacerts

If you don't want to add this parameter every time when you are trying to build [here is a solid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483514/how-to-pass-truststore-property-in-gradle-build-script) for that.